# $\sigma$-finite measure and semi-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $ (X, \Sigma, \mu)  $ it will be a space with measure.

$\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure if it exist sequence of sets $X_{i} \in \Sigma $ and $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_{i}=X$ and $\mu(X_{i})<\infty$ for all i

$\mu$ is semi-finite measure if for all $G \in \Sigma $ and $\mu (G)=\infty$ it exist $H \in \Sigma$ and $H \subset G$ and $0<\mu(H)<\infty$

Show that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure then $\mu$ is semi-finite measure

Comment: Changed "half-finite" to the English version "semi-finite".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Think about how you might show this for a specific, tangible sigma-finite space, like the real line, and then think about how to generalise your approach.

Comment: I've never seen the term "$\sigma$-semi-finite". Luckily you gavve a definition. That definition is the same as the standard definition of the standard term "semi-finite". So I changed it all to the standard terminology.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G\in \Sigma$ with $\mu(G) = \infty$. Choose $X_i \in \Sigma$ with $\cup_{i=1}^\infty X_i = X$ and $\mu(X_i) < \infty$ for all $i$ by the definition of $\sigma$-finite. Without loss of generality assume the $X_i$ are increasing (replace $X_i$ with $\cup_{j\leq i} X_i$)
Then
$$
G = \cup_{i=1}^\infty (G \cap X_i)
$$
so
$$
\infty = \mu(G) = \lim_{i} \mu(G \cap X_i).
$$
All the terms on the right side are finite by definition of $X_i$. So we have a sequence of finite numbers approaching $\infty$. In particular, they are not all $0$, because $\lim_i 0 = 0 \neq \infty$.
Hence one of them must be strictly positive, i.e. there is some $i$ for which $\mu(G \cap X_i) > 0$. Thus $H:= G \cap X_i$ suffices.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $G=G\cap X=G\cap(\bigcup_i X_i)=\bigcup_i(G\cap X_i)$.

Comment: Thanks for a hint but I still don't know how to do this exercise... Could u help me?

Comment: @user116011 If $(A_n)$ is a sequence of measurable sets, then $\mu\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\big)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mu\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^m A_m\big)$. Apply this with $A_n=G\cap X_n$.

Comment: Ok, but how do I know that measure>0 >

Comment: @user116011 The measure of what? Be a bit more concrete.